# Maven error - Downloading dependencies every time

Tags: jboss, maven, repository, maven-3

Whenever I build my app, Maven tries to download some dependencies.. I could see that on console (as shown below). Also I see some messages starting with

```
....no dependency information available
```

I am not understanding why it happens. And not once, it happens whenever I execute: **$mvn test**

It takes lot of time and I'm finding ways to suppress this.

```
[INFO] Building JBoss EJB 3.x Examples - Chapter 4: Calculator Service EJBs 1.1.
0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.1 is missing, no dependency info
rmation available

Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/com/s
un/xml/messaging/saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.4/saaj-impl-1.3.4.pom
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/
com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.4/saaj-impl-1.3.4.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/saaj-impl/
1.3.4/saaj-impl-1.3.4.pom

[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.4 is missing,
 no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/j
vnet/mimepull/1.4/mimepull-1.4.pom
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/
org/jvnet/mimepull/1.4/mimepull-1.4.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/mimepull/1.4/mimepull-1.4.p
om

[WARNING] The POM for org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.4 is missing, no dependency infor
mation available
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/g
lassfish/gmbal/gmbal-api-only/3.0.0-b023/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.pom
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/
org/glassfish/gmbal/gmbal-api-only/3.0.0-b023/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/gmbal/gmbal-api-only/3.
0.0-b023/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.pom

[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.0.0-b023 is missi
ng, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for ws-commons:policy:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency inform
ation available
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-beta-1:enforce (enforce-maven-environment)
@ jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ jboss-ej
b3-examples-ch04-firstejb ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Project-RND\EJB3\ch04-firstejb\src
\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jboss-ejb3-ex
amples-ch04-firstejb ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute Maven in offline mode to avoid downloading of dependencies everytime your build is run.

If you are using command line you can use `-o` as an argument.

Comment: perfect, 10years old and still works. I now use "mvn -o generate-sources" it was very annoying that maven redownloads stuff all the time. Really questionable why it does that.

Answer (score 2):

maven is doing this because it does not have these pom files in the local repository. Each time it runs it tries to fetch it.  @bhagyas has suggested a workaround, but you may want to relook at how these dependencies got downloaded without the pom

```
[WARNING] The POM for woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.1 is missing, no dependency info
rmation available
[WARNING] The POM for org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.4 is missing, no dependency infor
mation available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.4 is missing,
 no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.0.0-b023 is missi
ng, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for ws-commons:policy:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency inform
ation available
```